# Extracting title from pdf using pypdf2 not working

Tags: python-3.x, extract, pdfminer, pypdf

I'm trying to extract the title of PDF files using `pyPDF2`. The output is either none or a wrong title. I tried using `PDFminer` as well, still the same result. I tried using 3 different pdf files. Is there a better way to extract the title with better accuracy?
This is the code I used:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

def get_pdf_title(pdf_file_path):

    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(open(pdf_file_path, "rb")) 
    return pdf_reader.getDocumentInfo().title

title = get_pdf_title('C:/PythonPrograms/Test.pdf')

print(title)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you mean by Title of the PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working, at least for me on python 3.5.2. Check in the PDF properties that he indeed has a title.
PDF's title is part of its metadata, that needs to be set. It is not mandatory, not related to its content (other than by the will of the person writing it), nor with its filename.

If you use your snippet on a file with no title, it's output will be an empty string.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the PDF metadata. It works fine now.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.